# How to get windows console with no any startup text

Tags: windows, console

I've faced with problem when one batch script uses output from another script which is started from another instance of console. I cannot change script.

But I know why im having error. It's because each new instance of console outputs startup text like

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Active code page: 1251
```

Well I have to avoid this to appear. 
Anyone knows how to do this ?

This line `Active code page: 1251` is known because i set up custom codepage in registry in autorun string key. At least I want this to be silent.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: How are you managing to get the output of a script from another in such a way that you end up with the cmd intro text? Can you add a sample script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought, you need to change your "Autorun" value to smth like this

```
chcp 1251 > nul
```

Also, it is possible to remove version print, when you start cmd as `cmd.exe /k`